# How to access session object of express in socket.io

Tags: javascript, express, socket.io

I am using socket.io with express and using **express session** and **express-socket.io-session**, but I can't can't access properties of the express session in the socket.io session object and vice versa.

```
const server = require("http").createServer(app);
const client = require("socket.io").listen(server);

session = require("express-session")({
    secret: "my-secret",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
  }),
  sharedsession = require("express-socket.io-session");

app.use(session);
client.use(sharedsession(session, {
    autoSave:true
})); 

client.on("connection", (socket) => {

    socket.on("input", data => {
        console.log(socket.handshake.session.user)
        socket.handshake.session.name = "bar"
        socket.handshake.session.save()
    })

})


app.post("/signup", (req, res, next) => {
    req.session.user = "foo";
})


app.get("/test", (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.session.name)
})
```

Both `console.log()` return undefined, as it seems like they both are two different objects.

Comment: try socket.request.session

Comment: socket.request.session returns undefined

Answer (score 0):

I got my issue resolved, but can't seem to understand this weird issue when using `var socket = io('http://localhost:8080')` in the client HTML sock.io session id is differing from express session id, but when I do `var socket = io()` they both share the same session, and everything is working as expected.